# How do I refresh the page in ASP.NET? (Let it reload itself by code)

Tags: asp.net

How do I refresh a page in ASP.NET? (Let it reload itself by code)

I'd rather not use Response.Redirect() because I don't know if the page I will be on, as it's inside a user control inside a webpart inside sharepoint.

Comment: I'm not OP, but one reason may be because javascript can be disabled

Comment: ASP.NET relies on javascript, so if a user has javascript disabled there's a bigger problem ...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Once the page is rendered to the client you have only two ways of forcing a refresh.
One is Javascript

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", timeout);
```

The second is a Meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

You can set the refresh intervals on the server side.

Comment: where should i put the setTimeout?

Comment: Please see the answer from @gaurav below for a good way to do this in .NET using `Server.TransferRequest`.

Comment: This may be correct for a page not using Server Side support, however it is wrong in relation to the specified .Net The correct way is to use Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 421):

In my user controls, after updating data I do:

```
  Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

That ensures that the page is reloaded, and it works fine from a user control.  You use RawURL and not `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` to preserve any GET parameters that may be included in the request.

You probably don't want to use: `__doPostBack`, since many aspx pages behave differently when doing a postback.

Comment: @chris would you use a second parameter as Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false)? Apparently, it is the best practice when using reponse.redirect. What do you think?

Comment: @aleafonso: I have never personally used the 2nd parameter, and never had any issues as a consequence, so I'm not sure what it buys you.  But yes, according to the documentation, you should be using a 2nd parameter, but only if you're going to call CompleteRequest - which I have never bothered with.

Comment: Sometimes you might need AbsoluteUri, when the current page has an Id parameter (like a questionId here on stackoverflow). Or am I wrong?

Comment: @aleafonso is right - unless you need to halt all processing on the page, which is sometimes indicative of poor design plannning, you should pass a false as the second param. Not passing the 2nd param, or passing true, throws an HttpException and can impact performance and fill up event logs.

Answer (score 54):

This might be late, but I hope it helps someone who is looking for the answer.

You can use the following line to do that:

```
Server.TransferRequest(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, false);
```

Try to avoid using `Response.Redirect` as it increases the steps in the process. What it actually does is:

1. Sends back the page with redirection header
2. The Browser redirects to the destination URL.

As you can see, the same outcome takes 2 trips rather than 1 trip.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that Server.Transfer() is a more efficient way than Response.Redirect()

Comment: This worked in cases where Response.Redirect did not work correctly.

Comment: I've found that this does not clear the state of pages, eg the set `.Text` in a `TextBox` or the `.Visible` status of a `Button`.

Comment: Dumb question: where in the source of my ASPX page do I put that line?

Answer (score 42):

Try this:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: It will just send a redirection page instead of the page, causing a loop that the browser will stop when it sees that it won't ever get a real page...

Comment: @Guffa that depends entirly on the context in which the redirect is used. If it's used in an action / code block that is specifically called based on an action or condition then it will only fire once every iteration and if coded correctly in isolation.

Comment: This can result in loss of session data after the redirect.  There's something about fully qualified urls that messes up sessions.

Answer (score 14):

Use javascript's [location.reload()](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_loc_reload.asp) method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function reloadPage()
  {
    window.location.reload()
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

There are various method to refresh the page in asp.net like...

**Java Script**

```
 function reloadPage()
 {
     window.location.reload()
 }
```

**Code Behind**

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
```

**Meta Tag**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600"></meta>
```

**Page Redirection**

```
Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx"); // Or whatever your page url
```

Comment: None of these methods reloaded my HTML images from the server. Are these methods all deprecated, or are they not intended to hard reload images?

Comment: @David.P  In that case, you need to check your application/website. If Meta Tag and java script is not working then its issue... check it once.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to do a full page refresh, then how about wrapping what you want to refresh inside of a UpdatePanel and then do an asynchronous postback?

Answer (score 4):

I personally need to ensure the page keeps state, so all the text boxes and other input fields retain their values. by doing meta refresh it's like a new post, IsPostBack is always false so  all your controls are in the initialized state again. To retain state put this at the end of your Page_Load(). create a hidden button on the page with an event hooked up, something like butRefresh with event butRefresh_Click(...). This code sets a timer on the page to fire a postback just like a user clicked the refresh button themselves. all state and session is retained. Enjoy! (P.S. you may need to put the directive in the @Page header  EnableEventValidation="false" if you receive an error on postback.

```
//tell the browser to post back again in 5 seconds while keeping state of all controls
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "refresh", "<script>setTimeout(function(){ " + ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(butRefresh, "refresh") + " },5000);</script>");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. If you use a redirect (or any other server technique) you will never send the actual page to the browser, only redirection pages.

You have to either use a meta tag or JavaScript to do this, so that you can reload the page after it has been displayed for a while:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "refresh", "window.setTimeout('window.location.reload(true);',5000);", true);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `page_load`, add this:

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
Response.Expires = -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.Write("<script>window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href </script>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 ways for solve this problem:
1) After the head tag

```
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
</head>
```

2) If your page hasn't head tag you must use Javascript to implement

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function RefreshPage()
  {
    window.location.reload()
  }
</script>
```

**My contact:**

http://gola.vn

Answer (score 2):

The only correct way that I could do page refresh was through JavaScript, many of top .NET answers failed for me.

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'> setTimeout('location.reload(true); ', timeout);</script>");
```

Put the above code in button click event or anywhere you want to force page refresh.

Comment: Will this hard reload also HTTP images from the server?

Answer (score 2):

for asp.net core 3.1

```
Response.Headers.Add("Refresh", "2");// in secound
```

and

```
Response.Headers.Remove("Refresh");
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but there is not much explanation, so perhaps I misunderstood?  I just added the first line to my existing code, between these 2 lines:
     Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ZipFileName)
     'Response.Headers.Add("Refresh", "2")
     Response.TransmitFile(ZipFilePath) 'File.FullName);