# User defined auto refresh webpage

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to make a user defined auto-refresh in asp.net , this `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="90" />` works but this
    `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%=REFRESHINTERVAL%>" />` doesn't work, REFRESHINTERVAL is an public integer.

Comment: What does it output in the HTML source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206507/how-to-refresh-the-page-in-asp-net-let-it-reload-itself-by-code

Comment: I was checking the output and now it works for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use ASPNET API like this `Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", REFRESHINTERVAL.ToString());`?

Comment: I did try that but now it works with the original code. Thanks anyway.