# ASP.NET Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

I just want my asp.net webpage to reload after changing my combobox selected value. So I did

```
    protected void MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
```

I used Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) according to
[How do I refresh the page in ASP.NET? (Let it reload itself by code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206507/how-to-refresh-the-page-in-asp-net-let-it-reload-itself-by-code)

But when I change selection in my combo page is not reloaded.

Why, how to do so ?

Comment: Pointless, you lose the drop down selection.

Comment: @Aristos wouldn't ViewState save the state?

Comment: The redirect you make here is reload the page and forget anything from previous selections, and viewstate. Only the post back can keep the previous data (and viewstate).

Comment: Remove the `Response.Redirect` and only place the `AutoPostBack=true` - with other words, your question is how to make the Redirect to work, and I say, DO NOT make redirect, only set the AutoPostBack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have defined the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on the control itself.

**Edit:** Enable `AutoPostback` on the control as well, like Abe Miessler points out.

```
AutoPostBack="true"  
OnSelectedIndexChanged="MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting autopostback = true.  You haven't posted your markup but I suspect that would fix it.