# Why asp.net dropdown with autopostback doesn't keep my selected value

Tags: asp.net

As advised here [ASP.NET Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl) doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737240/asp-net-response-redirectrequest-rawurl-doesnt-work/12737254#12737254) I did put autopostback = true on a dropdown list to reload my page.

But after reloading it resets also the selected item to first one.

How to keep my previous value before reloading the page then ? I thought autopostback would do that job ?

Comment: Do you have ViewState enabled (on the page and/or in web.config)?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you're not repopulating the dropdown list on postback.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateDropDownList();
}
```

will cause it to be reset every time.  Instead try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateDropDownList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird I've done what yo advised but it still doesn't keep the selection.

Comment: Hmm, between the two answers here, I can't think of anything else.  Almost every time I think it must be something else, it's always a case of re-populating the dropdown list or clearing it accidentally somewhere.  You can try editing your question above with some code if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 5):

This is very old question, but still I want to answer for others who might be referring this page :

When you have non-unique string in value of drop-down, you will always point to the first item of same value.

For example :

Text = "xyz" Value="0"

Text = "xyz1" Value="0"

Text = "xyz2" Value="0"

Text = "abc" Value="1"

when you select xyz or xyz1 or xyz2, after postback, it goes back to first item which has text as xyz. 
If you keep unique values, you will not face this issue. 
I wasted my time and finally got it resolved with this trick.

Comment: Even older still, just wanted to point out that this was my problem. Each value must be unique. Personally, I think that's stupid.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ensure the `Enable.ViewState` property is set to true.
2. And as suggested  by  cptSup... Make sure that that you are not populating/binding dropdown on page with `IsPostback` check

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure you are not checking the DropDownList.SelectedValue in the System.Web.UI.Page.Init method. Due to the ASP.NET page life cycle the SelectedValue won't be available till the System.Web.UI.Page.Load method. At least this was my experience, just now in ASP.NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to GMaster9's answer, in my case I had to put the text = value.
Simply making the values unique e.g. 1, 2, 3 ... did not help.
Thus :

Text = "xyz" Value="xyz"

Text = "xyz1" Value="xyz1"

Text = "xyz2" Value="xyz2"