# Refresh master page from content page

Tags: c#, master-pages

I want to refresh my master page from a User control which is on content page in update panel.
Problem is that my user control is in update panel and I cant take it out of that due to some reasons .Now I want to directly refresh my master page on button click of user control which is on content page.Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you jus want to refresh the page? look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206507/how-do-i-refresh-the-page-in-asp-net-let-it-reload-itself-by-code

Comment: not helpful dear...I want to refresh it on button click not by meta tag or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript will refresh the master page...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reloadPage()
{
 window.location.reload()
}
</script>
```