# Sendkey doesn't work on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendkeys

How can I use sendkey or `SendKeys.SendWait` in asp.net c#.

I want use it just on localhost.
It works in Visual studio but not on IIS, I changed `applicationPoolIdentity` to adminstrator but I always get the same problem "access denied".

Comment: Send keys where exactly? You cannot send keys to a client, is that what you are attempting?

Comment: This is a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to use `SendKeys`?

Comment: `Sendkeys` is part of System.Windows.Forms which is aimed at desktop  environment. Try using Javascript to achieve what you want.

Comment: So... you believe it is possible for a webpage to send keys to client? For example if the visited webpage would send ALT + F4 to the client it would close the browser?

Comment: It is working as designed.

Comment: I want to use it in this method "sp_DataReceived (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)"  to refresh my page when I get the data from the serial port.
If not how can I refresh my page in behind code ?

Comment: If you are using Web Forms, you can use an UpdatePanel.

Comment: I want use it just on LOCALHOST "Just on My Computer"

Comment: The application pool identity alone doesn't help because the IIS service is denied access to all desktop apis. You can enable this by checking "Allow service to interact with desktop" on the logon tab for the "World Wide Web Publishing Service". I'm not sure about the relation between the iis service process and the child process workers but that might do it. Regardless this is all very bad practice. Try using any IPC to do the action you want. If you absolutely must,  write a small executable the does the action and directly exposes an IPC endpoint for the server to use.

Comment: Since you want the page to be refreshed have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206507/how-do-i-refresh-the-page-in-asp-net-let-it-reload-itself-by-code

Comment: @TamirDaniely, thank you very much, it's what I am looking for.

Comment: FYI by bad practice I mean this is a very serious security hole. It opens up many extra ways to escalate an attack vector. You should never do this on a production site. If security is a concern, you should make sure that the IIS instance doesn't host anything else except the intended app, doesn't run any 3rd party plugins which may be less secure. And generally make sure the box doesn't have any credentials \ keys that access anything secure on your lan.

Answer (score 4):

`SendKeys` is a method used for desktop development, not web. It is a Windows function, and you can't access such operating system functions from the browser (think what would happen if you could!). You are restricted to what you have in the browser: HTML, Javascript and CSS.

If you want to perform changes on the loaded HTML, you probably should look into a Javascript solution.

Comment: Think what would happen if you could ? Nothing I'm in LOCALHOST ,iis and browsers are on the same OS

Comment: @MohamedNassiri When building websites, it is generally not a good idea to assume the web server will be the same machine as that running the web browser. Since, if you are planning to make that assumption, why use a website at all? A local app would be simpler.